# How to use DBeaver to connect to SQL Server? The server SQLEXPRESS is not configured to listen with TCP/IP

Tags: dbeaver

I am trying to use DBeaver (7.3.2) in Window to connect to my SQL Server 2019 Express in the same machine. In my SQL Server 2019 Express, I have a sample Northwind database loaded successfully. I have tested the connection in SQL Server 2019 using `sa` user and no issue.

[image]

I have checked `SQL Server Configuration Manager` > `SQL Server Network Configuration` and enable TCP/IP. And under `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration` > `Client Protocols`, the `TCP/IP` default port is 1433.

[image]

Back to DBeaver, when I click `Test Connection`, I got the error

> The server SQLEXPRESS is not configured to listen with TCP/IP.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the solution already from http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2007/04/jdbc-to-sql-server-express.html

After enabling TCP/IP, you have to find out which port number to use. SQL Server Express allocates a port dynamically each time it is started, so to find or configure the port number, continue using SQL Server Configuration Manager …

Select Properties from the TCP/IP context menu. The TCP/IP Properties dialog should open.
Select the IP Addresses tab.
In the IPAll node …
The TCP Dynamic Ports field shows the currently used port number. If you set that field to blank, then SQL Server Express should not automatically choose another port when it restarts.
Set the desired port number in the TCP Port field.
Press OK to apply your settings and close the dialog.

Reset both SQL Browser and SQL Server Express services

Comment: I find the setting in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> TCP/IP -> right click properties -> Ip Addresses tab -> IPAll -> TCP Dynamic Ports.  Using the port there allowed me to connect

Comment: For me, did the above but also needed to use the older connection SQL Server (Old Driver) connection type. Using dbeaver 23.3.5

Answer (score 12):

For me I installed SQL Server Express with the default instance named MSSQLSERVER and mixed-mode Authentication (both an SA user and my local Windows account).

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager expand **SQL Server Network Configuration** (NOT SQL Native Client vXX.0 Configuration) > select **Protocols for MSSQLSERVER** > **Enable TCP/IP**.

[image]

2. Next restart the two services **SQL Server** and **SQL Server Browser**, then try to connect via DBeaver.
   [image]